# How to get back to a crash line/thread when debugging in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

A program I'm debugging has crashed during debugging due to access violation reading unavailable memory.

I have been looking through the threads in the application and have accidentally closed the error message as well as lost the thread in which it occurred.

How can I navigate back to the thread that caused the crash and see the error message again?

Comment: If you are still debugging, resume (f5) and the exception should reoccur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things are helpful here.

1. Visual studio shows the last break as a black arrow in the thread list, even after you move to another thread:
   [image]
2. As @MichaelChourdakis pointed out in a comment, if the program has stopped on an access violation, you can use <kbd>▶ Continue</kbd> (F5) and the program will just jump back to the error.